# Confusion on equivalent functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I want to show there is a measurable function $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ which isn't equivalent to any real continuous function on $[0,1]$.

So I say, consider

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 
      1, &  x \geq \frac{1}{2} \\
      0, & 0 < x <\frac{1}{2}
   \end{cases}
$$

This step function is $\mu$-measurable because it is a simple function. Two functions $f$ and $g$ are **equivalent** (w.r.t a measure $\mu$) if $$\mu \{x \mid f(x) \neq g(x)\} = 0$$

So I need to show that there is no continuous function $g(x)$ is equivalent to our step function $f(x)$. I am stuck on how I actually show this. I know our function $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $x = \frac{1}{2}$.

Could someone shove me in the right direction?

Comment: The key fact is that Lebesgue-negligible sets have dense complement.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I'm not quite sure what that means. I know that if we have two sets $A$, $B$ of a metric space then $A$ is said to be **dense** in $B$ if $cl(A)$ contains $B$. what is meant by Lebesgue-negligible sets?

Comment: Precisely what I mean, as far as density is concerned. I presume your $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure on the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue-measurable sets, is it not?

Comment: Yes, that is my $\mu$, but I don't understand what "Lebesgue-negligible" means and how it connects to me problem. Sorry, I am still learning definitions.

Comment: $S$ is negligible with respect to $\mu$ if $\mu(S)=0$.